# Question about torsion group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my book, it says that torsion group is a group all of whose elements have finite order.

It seems to me that then every subgroup of finite group must be torsion group since if group is finite, then subgroup is finite. Saying subgroup is finite is equivalent to saying that order of element in subgroup is finite.

Is it right?

Comment: Yes but it only goes one way, it can be that every element is torsion but the group is infinite.

Comment: I think it's important to point out that the torsion *subset* is not always a *subgroup*.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the set of torsion elements of any finite group is just the group.  This follows from the fact that the elements of a finite group always have finite order.

The statement that a subgroup is finite is equivalent to its elements having finite order is not quite right.  The infinite group $\Bbb{Z}_2^{\infty}$ is a counter example (all its elements have order $2$).